# How to write build phase run script to encrypt image files in the sub directoryies

Tags: macos, cocoa, unix

I need to encrypt my resource image files in my project so I used [NK-Encrypter](https://github.com/DiamondTechIT/NK-Encrypter/blob/master/webViewOnLoad/EncryptedFileURLProtocol.m)
and I write run script like this

```
DIRNAME=ImageFiles/Images
RESOURCES=Resources
ENC_KEY="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456"

INDIR=$PROJECT_DIR/$DIRNAME
OUTDIR=$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/$RESOURCES/$DIRNAME

if [ ! -d "$OUTDIR" ]; then
mkdir -p "$OUTDIR"
fi

for file in "$INDIR"/*
                     do
                     echo "Encrypting $file"
                     "$PROJECT_DIR/crypt" -e -k $ENC_KEY -i "$file" -o "$OUTDIR/`basename "$file"`"
                     done
```

it will encrypt the image files contains in Images folder. Now I need to encrypt ImageFiles directory it contain lot of sub directory.The above script is encrypt only one sub directory I need to encrypt all sub directories in one script. How would you do this?

Update:

```
DIRNAME=ImageFiles/Images
        RESOURCES=Resources
        ENC_KEY="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456"

        INDIR=$PROJECT_DIR/$DIRNAME
        OUTDIR=$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/$RESOURCES/$DIRNAME

        if [ ! -d "$OUTDIR" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$OUTDIR"
        fi

     for file in $`find $INDIR -type f`
        do
        echo "Encrypting $file"
        "$PROJECT_DIR/crypt" -e -k $ENC_KEY -i "$file" -o "$OUTDIR/`basename "$(dirname ${file})"`/`basename "$file"`"
        done
```

Finally I got encrypt sub directory using above code. I have faced another problem when the directoryh or file contain space it shows error `Shell Script Invocation Error Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1` how can I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line

```
for file in "$INDIR"/*
```

with

```
for file in `find "$INDIR" -type f`
```

Comment: but it will encrypt all image files in one directory.I need to encrypt within a same sub directories.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to say.  What is meant by "within a same sub directories"?

Comment: All image files are encrypted in ImageFiles(refer code above) directory not in sub directories.

Comment: its show error Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1. But in resource path all image files are encrypted in one directory.

Comment: "/Users/eventurersmac11/Desktop/Easyphoto/crypt: Can't open input file"
this error also occured

Comment: Fine.I got it now how can i get sub directory names.

Comment: Please don't update questions after weeks.  Post a new one; it'll make things easier for you and people to figure.